# How to format a fixed length string

Tags: c#, string

I have a fixed length string `ABCDEFGHIJK`, is there a way to convert this into `AB-CDEFGHIJ-K` using string format?

Comment: Use `.Substring` to break the string up into sections and then add in the hyphens when you build it back into a single string.

Comment: As this is a simple problem, yes, there are many ways to do it.  I've voted to close this question as too broad because, unless you add some scope to the question or provide some code that hasn't worked for you, this just turns into single-language [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: var s = "ABCDEFGHIJK".Insert(2, "-").Insert(11, "-");

Comment: yes, it's a simple problem, i wanted to know if it is possible to do it with string format. No errors on code, just wanted the knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a fixed length string ABCDEFGHIJK, is there a way to convert
> this into AB-CDEFGHIJ-K using string format?

Focusing on the "string format" part, we can implement [IFormatProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=net-6.0). This will format the string if it is EXACTLY eleven characters long, otherwise it just returns the same string back. Following the example, the "H" format stands for "hypenated":

```
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
    string output = String.Format(new MyStringFormat(), "Formatted: {0:H}", input);
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}

public class MyStringFormat : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    
    object IFormatProvider.GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
        {
            return this;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    string ICustomFormatter.Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (arg.GetType() != typeof(String))
        {
            try
            {
                return HandleOtherFormats(format, arg);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                throw new FormatException(String.Format("The format of '{0}' is invalid.", format), e);
            }
        }

        string ufmt = format.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (ufmt != "H")
        {
            try
            {
                return HandleOtherFormats(format, arg);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                throw new FormatException(String.Format("The format of '{0}' is invalid.", format), e);
            }
        }

        string result = arg.ToString();
        if (result.Length != 11)
            return result;                
        else
            return result.Insert(2, "-").Insert(11, "-"); // see comment by Hans Passant!
    }

    private string HandleOtherFormats(string format, object arg)
    {
        if (arg is IFormattable)
            return ((IFormattable)arg).ToString(format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        else if (arg != null)
            return arg.ToString();
        else
            return String.Empty;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var s = "ABCDEFGHIJK";

Console.WriteLine($"{s[..2]}-{s[2..10]}-{s[^1..]}");
```

Answer (score 2):

howabout

```
var newstring = String.format("{0}-{1}-{2}", s.Substring(0,2), s.Substring(3,7), s.Substring(10,1))
```

you could also use interpolation and the new range stuff

Answer (score 1):

`var f = Regex.Replace("ABCDEFGHIJK", "^(..)(.*)(.)$", "$1-$2-$3");`

...yeah, I know.

Also, dropping the `{2}`, etc. was inspired by Yuriy's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3968916/1048799).

Comment: Hahaha blast from the past answer. Interesting to know I haven't changed in 12 years.

Answer (score 0):

The Rube Goldberg way perhaps:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string code = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
        string mask = "##-########-#";

        Console.WriteLine(code.Format(mask));
        // AB-CDEFGHIJ-K
    }

    public static string Format(this string code, string mask, char token = '#')
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(mask.Length);
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in mask)
        {
            if (item==token)
            {
                sb.Append(code[index++]);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(item);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

**Edit 1**

replaced the space `' '` character placeholder with the pound sign `'#'` for better clarity.